# How come php script works on 1 server, not on other

Tags: php, curl

I have a local WAMP server running with a webapplication.
I also have a webserver (rented) somewhere on the internet.

I want to receive data from webforms with either post or get. Once data is received a controller needs to do some stuff like validation and storing and next a few headers need to be set.

I have this working on my WAMP environment, copied the script to the rented webserver, ran the same script and... no cigar...

It seems that i dont get a response back from the cURL request on the rented webserver. (The webforms need to send in data 'underwater', thought i'd pick this up with cURL)

Weird thing is, it does work on my WAMP server. On my local environment id do get a response back, which i can handle and display.

Without looking at any code, what would be the thing that stops my script for working on the rented webserver?

- Both have JSON and cURL enabled.
- Local is PHP 5.5.12
- rented webserver is PHP 5.5.21

Using a simple cURL method, not doing anything fancy:

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
```

On my local environment i get a response (i set headers on success and failure), on the rented server i don't get anything, with an exact copy of the scripts.

What could be things, like server settings or anything else, that would break my script?

I have ini_set('display_errors', true); above all scripts but even that does not tell me anything.

I am lost. Please help.

Comment: What does your web server's error log say? Have you considered using `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`, or [`debug_print_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) ?

Comment: There can be many issues so try these: `echo curl_error($ch);` after `curl_exec($ch);` could prove useful. Make sure `error_reporting(E_ALL);` is set as well. It is possible that your rented server's IP is blacklisted.

Comment: Did try 'on', didnt help at all.

Comment: Or you can try to ping that domain first or to open it with a browser like lynx. That if it's not an obvious thing, like a name that only works in your system (localhost, something defined in your hosts file, etc).

Comment: "Warning: curl_error(): 3 is not a valid cURL handle resource in" is the response i get from echo curl_error($ch);

Comment: You must call it before curl_close

Comment: Where did you put it? Update your question with your new script

Comment: stoopid.. ofcourse, should be before close.

Comment: ok, i now get that the host could not be resolved. This can be true, because the host i am using is not in any DNS server yet. It is a temp one which i get to via the host file on my computer. ... Ok.. How can i solve this? Weirdly enough, 'Localhost' seems fine...

Comment: maybe by doing the same thing? the hosts file.. http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file

Comment: Instead of a domain name, you can use a direct IP address for your cURL if only one website is hosted on that IP.

Comment: It's not weird.. localhost works because that's a webserver

Comment: Now that i wrote this all down and finally got that error back.. it starts to land here aswell.. This is totally expected once you see that (i already said it myself) it's running on a domain that does not exist. Ergo, the cURL cant find the server it's looking for. Too stoopid...